# Toggle / untoggle font size document.execCommand

Tags: javascript, toggle, contenteditable

I am working on a little script here using contenteditable.

It's toggling / untoggling bold, underline, italic, but I can't make it untoggle font-size. It toggles it and then it stays that way.

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/zesaj9ck/2/

```
<button id="toggle_bolt" onclick="document.execCommand('italic');">toggle italic</button>
<button id="toggle_bolt" onclick="document.execCommand('underline');">toggle underline</button>
<button id="toggle_bolt" onclick="document.execCommand('fontSize', false, 7);">toggle size</button>

<div id="wmd-input" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not "toggling" or changing at all after the first click because each click just sets the size to 7. Font size doesn't just have two states like bold, italic, and underline. The working example below takes a specified size value from an input instead.

I also recommend moving your click handlers to functions, as I've done with the `changeSize` function. This creates a clearer separation of concerns and improves maintainability.

```js
function changeSize(increase) {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('size').value, 10) + (increase ? 1 : -1);
  
  document.execCommand('fontSize', false, value);
  document.getElementById('size').value = value;
}
```

```css
#wmd-input {
  width : 500px;
  min-height : 100px;
  border : 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<button id="toggle_bolt" onclick="document.execCommand('bold');">toggle bolt</button>
<button id="toggle_bolt" onclick="document.execCommand('italic');">toggle italic</button>
<button id="toggle_bolt" onclick="document.execCommand('underline');">toggle underline</button>
<button id="toggle_bolt" onclick="changeSize(true)">Size +</button>
<button id="toggle_bolt" onclick="changeSize(false)">Size -</button>
<input id="size" value="4" readonly />
<div id="wmd-input" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: I see. Taking your example, how can I completely eliminate the button for the fontSize and just have a dropdown option where I can simply select a font size? Is it possible to do?

Comment: @VitalSigns Sure, attach a `change` on `input` event to an input type `number`, and run `execCommand` inside the handler. I'll update this answer with an example, but you really should new questions if you want to continue asking beyond the original scope of this question.

Comment: I realize I am asking beyond my original question, but as good as your answer was it's not practical to be used on a website. You'd agree with that right? I need a solution that can be used by an actual user.

Comment: @VitalSigns StackOverflow isn't really for extended discussion meant to output production-ready code. Your question was good, because it asked specifically about _toggling font size with `execCommand`_, and that's what I answered.  The information here will get you to the next step, at which point you can ask more questions. With that said, I'm happy to help get you closer to your goal, and I've updated it with a slightly different example. Actually using a `select` element would need a little more effort, because selecting an option from that steals focus from the highlighted text.